# Modifying shutdown script

Tags: macos

I'm looking for the location of the system script that calls /sbin/shutdown. I want to change the flags so when the machine is shutdown from the finder, it halts the machine, but doesn't power off.

Alternately, I'd like to force the setting that "Start up automatically after a power failure" checks on power applied to start the machine *every* time the power comes on.

Is there a way to enforce a dirty shutdown without trashing the filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

In OS X, the shutdown is not done by `/sbin/shutdown` in a standard GUI setting.

If you want to perform something when a login or logout occurs, use login/logout hooks described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Articles/CustomLogin.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002134-111735).